# How to use current filename multiple times in a pipe command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to convert batch of .mov files to mp4. 
How can I get filename from pipe to generate ffmpeg command? How to use pipe argument multiple times in the chain link?
I'm trying to have something like that:

```
 ls *.MOV | ffmpeg -y -i $file  "$file.mp4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes are useful when you want to use the *standard output* of one command as the *standard input* of another command. But you need to pass a file as input to `ffmpeg`, not filenames on its standard input. And you need to run `ffmpeg` multiple times, once for each input file to get an output file.

Long story short, pipes are not useful for this, you need a loop as the other answer suggested. But should double-quote the filename parameters:

```
for file in *.MOV; do
    ffmpeg -y -i "$file" "$file.mp4"
done
```

You mentioned in a comment that you could write a Perl script. That would be really overkill. Bash is a simpler, perfectly suitable approach. Note that you could write the above script on a single line, and run it directly on the command line.

```
for file in *.MOV; do ffmpeg -y -i "$file" "$file.mp4"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a simple `for` loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /path/to/*.MOV
do

    echo "Converting $file"
done
```

Comment: I can write it perl script, but I what to use pipes for that,  to understand pipes concept.